# What is the relation between J48 algorithm and decisionStump algorithm on weka?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka

I have the test results on Weka and in the some of data sets there is not much difference between them when using J48 and decisionStump as an algorithm.

How could J48 algorithm have no statistically significant difference to DecisionStump algorithm when comparing by accuracy (percent correct)? Can we find the relation by examining algorithms or structure of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DecisionStump is intended to be a very basic building block for other classifiers, but perhaps your data happen to be adequately modeled with a simple classifier, in which case J48 will be unable to find a clever answer that is better. Degenerate cases of this are:

1) DecisionStump always produces the right answer because one of the predictors in fact completely predicts the right answer.

2) All of the predictors are completely useless, in which case DecisionStump is no different than everything else.

I'm not at all surprised because I keep seeing studies that say that no one model was spectacularly better than the others. See e.g. the abstract at http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.6753. Usually logistic regression is one of the "good enough" classifiers.